# bypass __all__ is it possible?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Through  an import, I need to access to a "private" function (`_minimize_cg` in optimize Scipy module), but this private function isn't in `__all__` definition (of course).
Is it possible to bypass this "protection" to access to the function.

(https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L1101)

from scipy.optimize import _minimize_cg

--> ImportError: cannot import name _minimize_cg

Thanks.

PS: Python 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__all__` only affects when importing using `from module import *`. If you just import the module, or a module member explicitely, then it has no effect:

```
from module import memberThatIsNotInAll

import module
module.memberThatIsNotInAll
```

It’s not a protection, or access modifier, it’s just a setting to avoid namespace pollution when importing everything from a module.

Comment: Are you sure the function is even there? scipy 0.12.0 on my system `scipy.optimize._minimize_cg` doesn't seem to exist at all, so importing it is out of the question.

Comment: @oam31 `scipy.optimize` refers to the [*package*](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/__init__.py) which only contains the filtered members. If you want to import [`_minimize_cg`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L1122), you need to do `from scipy.optimize.optimize import _minimize_cg`.

Comment: @Steve Yes in scipy 0.14 see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L1101

Comment: @poke Perfect ! Which is the difference between from scipy.optimize import _minimize_cg   and from scipy.optimize.optimize import _minimize_cg

Comment: `scipy.optimize` is the *package* (the folder, which is represented by the `__init__.py` file), and `scipy.optimize.optimize` is the actual module in that package (the `optimize.py` file). if you only import the former, then you only get access to the member that are in the `__init__.py` file, and there, the `from optimize import *` syntax is used, so the filtering by `__all__` *is* taken into account.

Comment: @poke THANKS for your explanations